# Как задать максимальную высоту изображения?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
У меня есть экран с одной новостью: изображение + заголовок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новости подкачиваются через RSS-рассылку, и, соотвественно, изображение то есть, то нет.

Я не хочу ставить заглушку.
У меня была следущая идея: прописать в макете 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" и указать maxHeight.
Следовательно, если бы изображения не было, был бы только заголовок. (в мои мечтах)

Но, как указано на [сайте разработчиков](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minHeight), есть только android:minHeight.

Вопрос: Есть ли способ решить данную проблему через верстку? 
Если нет, то как вы обычно с этим справляетесь?

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `.setVisibility(View.GONE);` когда нет картинки и `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`, когда она есть. Изначально в `xml`-разметке также укажите для картинки `android:visibility="gone"`.

Когда нет картинки - ничего не будет, когда она есть - будет отображаться как Вам необходимо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать сделать следующим образом:

В интересующем изображении в макете указать

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:maxHeight="250dp" (нужная вам высота)`

в MainActivity задать метод, который будет рассчитывать эту высоту

```
 public int getWindowHeightForImage() {
    return (int) Math.round(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() * 0.4);
}
```

В адаптере прописать переменную для высоты (часть кода убрала, показана только относящаяся непосредственно к вопросу часть)

```
public class NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private int mImageViewHeight; // вот эта переменная

public NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<News> items, int imageViewHeight) {
    mImageViewHeight = imageViewHeight;
}
```

Указать это значение в холдере

```
 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mNewsImage;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mNewsImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.one_news_main_picture);
        mNewsImage.getLayoutParams().height = mImageViewHeight; // наша переменная
```

и передать во фрагмент нашего одного элемента из списка

```
private void setAdapter() {
    mAdapter = new NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), results, ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getWindowHeightForImage());}
```

я понимаю, что очень коряво сейчас как-то объяснила, но оно работает.